# How can I get a list of document with specific value of attribute in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question, for example I have a collection of users with an attribute of id, hobby, name. All of them are string and hobby is an id that refer to hobby id in hobby collection. How can I get the list of user that has the same hobby. Assume that I have a class called user that has attribute id, hobby, name. Also I have a collection of hobby with attribute id,name of the hobby. I still can't differentiate between querySnapshot,documentSnapshot,documentReference.

My collections are look like this user is (id,hooby_id,name) and hobby collection is (id,hobby_name). and my function query is like public list <"user"> getUserByHobby (String Hobby){...}.  the user in the return is not string, its an object of user.

How can I limit the number of queries? How can I sort by alphabet in this case? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
db.collection("users")
        .whereEqualTo("hobby", "travelling")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        // Logging the ID of your desired document & the document data itself
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

For more, check the official documentation:

[Cloud Firestore Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

(As these are basic operations and pretty elaboratively covered on the documentation.)

Comment: which one should I return if I want a list<user>, also I just add that hobby has their own collection. so now the hobby in user collection is a an id's of a hobby. Thank you

Comment: Look inside ```if(task.isSucessful())``` block, where you may see a ```for``` loop. This loop iterates through the documents that are returned from your collection. So, if you want to store the list of documents, you can store them in a local array or something.

Comment: And about the other requirement, you can read the hobby collection first. Store the hobbies (Or just the ids of the hobbies) in a local array. And then use that array elements (hobby ids) to make queries to find users with specific hobby.

Comment: ahhh ok thanks for the idea, is there any exception that I have to throw in the queries? Thank you

Comment: Not quite sure about that. You may give it a try and post later if you face any other problem.

Comment: Is there any return for your code like boolean or something?

Comment: If the task of fetching the documents become successful, ```if (task.isSuccessful()) {}```, this portion gets executed. If any error occurs, ```else {}```, this portion gets executed.

Comment: Thank you, can you help more about how to limit number of queries and how to sort it. And what happen if task is null?

Comment: There ```.limit()``` and ```.orderBy()``` method provided by the firebase. You may easily find them in their documentation.

Comment: Then about the question when task is null?

Comment: You can Log the returned task or show the task as a Toast to understand the structure of the returned value.

Comment: @FarhanKhalifa please, mark the answer as accepted if you think that smmehrab helped you.